# Get row position in onCreateContextMenu

Tags: android, contextmenu

I'm trying to create a context menu that changes the available options depending on which row was clicked.

But I can't figure out how to get the row position in the listview for row that was clicked, until after the menu is created.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

It is not obvious at all, but here's the code:

```
   public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
   {    
        AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
        int position = info.position;
```

Comment: @TusharAgarwal I'm facing similar problem, have you found any alternative

Comment: @VinayBhargav Have you registered for contextMenu ?  like .. 
`registerForContextMenu(getListView());`

Comment: @TusharAgarwal yeah .. i'm using gridview .. I've gone through many posts .. nothing helped me :|

Comment: I've got it working finally, I was using custom GridView in which `getContextMenuInfo()` method was not implemented. I've posted [here](http://vinaybhargav.wordpress.com/2014/07/20/android-floating-context-menu-for-listviewgridview/) in case if someone need a sample.

Answer (score 0):

The above solution did not work for me. Here is what I used:

```
@Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                                    ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, context.getString(R.string.tabTitleEnrolment));
        menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, context.getString(R.string.tabTitleAfterCare));
        menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, context.getString(R.string.contextMenuDelete));

        pos = getPosition();
    }
```